# polylang: Error 404 Page not found error

Tags: wordpress

Except home all the links return an error 404 page not found.

I installed and activated polylang plugin in order to add arabic language , the home page for english and arabic works but other pages return a 404 page

Answer (score 2):

@SOS-Mona you have to create pages for every page you have and assign them to arabic. Have you done that already? And assing the Language Switcher in the menu section. Also try to flush the permalinks

Comment: already done. I created pages for every page. the problem was that on the link of the arabic pages I have arabic letters once I changed it(the link), the pages are here with no 404 error page

Comment: Did you also flush the permalinks from Settings -> Permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it. For anyone who is out there having the same issue: Polylang must be confusing because you might having two original different homepages (with a blank translation of itself) for each language instead of making a translation page.
Just delete the duplicate one and create another translation from the orgiginal by clicking on the flag. Then you'll be set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**Solution**  
Edit page in your language, then set it to secondary language, then update page.
 Set language back to primary language and in "**languages settings**" on page begin retype title of page in secondary language.
 WP should show title then Save page.
 Go to "**permanent links**" change settings to default, save, and set it again to the one prefer.

To me, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem today after adding 2 new languages.

First language worked well, second one had all pages in 404.
I've searched a solution for a couple of hours, and the solution was to go to permalinks settings and just revalidate... Hope this helps others !